# How to disable auto-updates for the Azure Pipelines agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-agent

I want to disable automatic updates for Azure Pipelines Agent.
Earlier this was a setting in the Agent pools -> Azure Pipelines -> Settings, but I don't see it now.

It used to be like this:

[image]

Now it looks like this. There is no settings tab

[image]

How to disable Auto-Updates?

Comment: According to MSFT resource Merry Meng[MSFT] and document shared by her, It seems that they don’t have a feature now to allow you disable auto update.
And the agent only updates if you use a feature or task that demands a new version of the agent. Reference document-
 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-windows-self-hosted-agent-how-to-disa/794752

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2455

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to check my answer below. Hope the information may help resolve your concerns.

Comment: Hi @visualreactor, May I know if by any chance my answer can address your concerns. If yes, would you consider marking this answer, which will benefit others with similar concerns? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshots that you shared, please note that the agent pool with the name of `Azure Pipelines` is the Microsoft-hosted agent pool. With [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), maintenance and upgrades are taken care of by Microsoft.

For the other agent pools like `Default`, you can use it to register [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) that you've set up.

Microsoft-hosted agents are always kept up-to-date. If the newer version of the agent is only different in minor version, self-hosted agents can usually be updated automatically (configure this setting in Agent pools, select your agent, Settings - the default is enabled) by Azure Pipelines.

See more details in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#agent-version-and-upgrades)